# C++ [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)[2]' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and I keep getting an error when I am calling my function. I am trying to get the user to input a value for the array and then get it to display it in a table format. Also, I am trying to display a 3x3 matrix in the end.

```
void DMMatrix(int DM[2][2]){

int number;

    cout << "Input 0's and 1's to the DM[2][2]\n\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            cout << "DM[" << i << "]"<< "[" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> number;
            DM[i][j] = number;
        }
    }   
}

int main(){
int i, j, sum = 0;
int DM[2][2];   
    
    DMMatrix(DM[2][2]); 
    cout << "\n\nOutput (table format)\n\n";
    
    for(i = 0;i < 3;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < 3;j++){
            cout << "   " << DM[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    
    sum = DM[0][0] + DM[0][1] + DM[0][2] + DM[1][0] + DM[1][1] + DM[1][2] + DM[2][0] + DM[2][1] + DM[2][2]; 
    
    if (sum % 2 == 0){
        cout << "\nSum is " << sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: First rule of coding: Make problems small. Isolate the bug.

Comment: Why are you passing `DM[2][2]` just pass the name of array `DM` as `DMMatrix(DM)`

Comment: Unrelated: given `int DM[2][2]`, rethink the exit condition in `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` and its friends.

Comment: You could put  the `sum` calculation inside a nested `for` loop; or place the `sum` calculation inside your input loop.

Comment: Thank you for those who are helping me. I am still trying to learn the terms you guys are saying so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 **problems** in your program.

**Mistake 1**

You are calling the function `DMMatrix` incorrectly. The correct way to call `DMMatrix` would be:

```
DMMatrix(DM);//CORRECT WAY OF CALLING DMMatrix
```

**Mistake 2**

Your 2D array `DM` has 2 rows and 2 columns and you're accessing 3rd row and 3rd column of the array `DM`. But since the 3rd row and 3rd column doesn't exist, you have **undefined behavior** in your program. To solve this you can create a `3x3` 2D array as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void DMMatrix(int DM[3][3]){//2 CHANGED TO 3
int number;

    cout << "Input 0's and 1's to the DM[2][2]\n\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            cout << "DM[" << i << "]"<< "[" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> number;
            DM[i][j] = number;
        }
    }   
}

int main(){
int i, j, sum = 0;
int DM[3][3];   //2 CHANGED TO 3
    
    DMMatrix(DM); 
    cout << "\n\nOutput (table format)\n\n";
    
    for(i = 0;i < 3;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < 3;j++){
            cout << "   " << DM[i][j] << "  ";
            sum += DM[i][j];//CALCULATE SUM HERE
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    
    
    
    cout << "\nSum is " << sum;
    
}
```

**Mistake 3**

You don't **need to** calculate the `sum` by writing each element of the array explicitly. You can calculate the `sum` inside the `for` loop in my modified above program. Also note that in your *original code*, while calculating the `sum` you were going **out of bounds** which leads to **undefined behavior**. The above shown program corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

First, the size of the array that you have given to `DM` is 2x2 but your loop runs for 9 times considering the loop runs for 0, 1 and 2 which will cause a *stack smash* or *Segmentation Fault*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void DMMatrix (int DM[3][3])
{

  int number;
  cout << "Input 0's and 1's to the DM[2][2]\n\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
          cout << "DM[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]: ";
          cin >> number;
          DM[i][j] = number;
      }
    }
}

int main ()
{
  int i, j, sum = 0;
  int DM[3][3];
  DMMatrix (DM);
  cout << "\n\nOutput (table format)\n\n";
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
          cout << "   " << DM[i][j] << "  ";
      }
      cout << "\n";
    }

  sum = DM[0][0] + DM[0][1] + DM[0][2] + DM[1][0] + DM[1][1] + DM[1][2] +
    DM[2][0] + DM[2][1] + DM[2][2];

  if (sum % 2 == 0)
    {
      cout << "\nSum is " << sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Proper terminology is Undefined Behaviour. Practically I'd expect a smashed stack, but the implementation could do anything.